# How can I draw the following plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have two plots. How can I draw them?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? There are so many ways, we need some more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), for example:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\Unit{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node[fill=white] 
  at (\Unit/3,\Unit/3)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};

\begin{scope}[shift={(2*\Unit,0)}]
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node
  at (\Unit,1.3*\Unit)
  (Last)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\draw[->] 
  (\Unit/2,\Unit/2) -- (Last);  
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In a comment it was required to give a caption to each plot. I show two possibilities here: the first one, using one `figure` environment for each plot, and the second one with just one `figure` and two `minipage`s so they are side-by-side:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\Unit{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node[fill=white] 
  at (\Unit/3,\Unit/3)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{the first figure}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node
  at (\Unit,1.3*\Unit)
  (Last)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\draw[->] 
  (\Unit/2,\Unit/2) -- (Last);  
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{the second figure}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node[fill=white] 
  at (\Unit/3,\Unit/3)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{the first figure}
\label{fig:testc}
\end{minipage}% <- don't delete this percentage symbol!
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] 
  (-0.5,0) -- (\Unit+0.5,0);
\draw[->] 
  (0,-0.5) -- (0,\Unit+0.5);
\draw
  (0,\Unit) -- (\Unit,\Unit) -- (\Unit,0) -- cycle;
\node
  at (\Unit,1.3*\Unit)
  (Last)
  {$L^{\ast}$};
\draw[->] 
  (\Unit/2,\Unit/2) -- (Last);  
\node[left] at (0,\Unit) {$1$};
\node[below] at (\Unit,0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{the second figure}
\label{fig:testd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code is very perfect. Thank you. Is that possible that I add separately captions to these plots?

Comment: @DavidMayar Use a `tikzpicture` environment for each plot, remove the `scope` environment from the second one and surround each one with a `figure` environment with its `\caption`. I can provide an example of the code but first tell me if they should be treated as two independant figures or as two subfigures.

Comment: I want to consider each of them as an independent figure.

Comment: @DavidMayar Please see my updated answer.